# Rails4 - AJAX request to items controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

```
$(document).ready ->
 #... other code ...
  $("#item-select2").click ->
    #alert "item was clicked!" #this code works
```

Inside the on click call, I am trying to send an AJAX request to items controller (method 'show') with id of selected item. Inside the controller#show I want to find our item and return it as json.

I have a form where when a specific item is selected in the dropdown, then I want to display the price for that item so I need to retrieve it through the AJAX but I am not sure how. If anyone can guide me, that would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Jbuilder

[Continuation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020554/rails-json-api-returning-an-price-of-an-item-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a dropdown, you need to listen for change event, execute the Ajax call and put the price into the element you want, eg:

```
$(document).ready ->
    $("#item-select2").change ->
        selectedItem = $(this)
        $.ajax([
            "/items"
            "/"
            selectedItem.val()
            ".json"
       ].join("")).done (item) ->
            $(".price").html item.price
```

On the Rails side, you need to specify that your controller responds to JSON
by adding `respond_to :json` on top of your controller, below of you before action line, eg

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
   respond_to :json, :html
```

also into your show action update your response, so you support both html and json, in case you are not using some json serializer such as jbuilder, if you do, so you don't need to add these changes:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json  { render json: @item.to_json }
  end
end
```

Hope this help you,

Cheers

Comment: This has worked for me, I am using jbuilder so I didn't need to change anything in the controller.

Comment: The only thing is that the dropdown is multi selection so if I select more than one item, it results in getting json like so: `items/1,2.json`

Comment: ok if you got multiple select them you have two options:


1 - send an ajax request for each selected option 

2 - create an JSON api into rails that returns the price of a given item list

Comment: [Continuation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020554/rails-json-api-returning-an-price-of-an-item-list)

Answer (score 0):

You need the item ID for the selected option. You might do that like this:

```
var itemId = $('#items').find(':selected').attr('id');
```

With the item ID, you can make a `GET` request to the show action. Check the [jQuery.get() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for examples. You may also need to add a `respond_to` block in your controller action with JS support. The ajax request might look like this:

```
$.get("/items" + itemId, function(data) {
  $(".price").html(data['price']);
});
```

If rails controller action sent the price for the item back to the JS like this:

```
render json: {price: @item.price}
```

Comment: `var itemId = $('#items').find(':selected').attr('id');` I get item undefined

Comment: I am not sure how to modify this code for my purpose, @luster's code worked though

Comment: Ok, that was meant to be example code, which is why I said "might". I also wasn't sure if you were using coffeescript or JS . The difference in the luster example above is using `val()` on the option elements instead of looking at the `id` attribute value.

Comment: I appreciate your time, would I be able to use this way for a multi dropdown selection? from my previous comment, I did not know how to modify `var itemId = $('#items').find(':selected').attr('id');` to work with my app. `$("#item-select2").change ->` triggers when an item is selected.

Comment: Yes you're right, you need some UI event binding code in addition, like what luster wrote above. The code from luster binds to a "change" event on the dropdown/select menu, which is typical. If you need more practice with this, I'd spend some time reading and trying out jquery tutorials on event binding and DOM manipulation. Good luck.