# Rails, JSON api returning prices of an item list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a multi select dropdown box and was advised to create a JSON api into rails that returns the price of a given item list but not sure how, looking for guidance.

#### orders.js.coffee

```
  $("#item-select2").click ->
   selectedItem = $(this)
   #alert selectedItem.val()
   if selectedItem.val()?
       $.ajax([
        "/items"
        "/"
        selectedItem.val()
        ".json"
        ].join("")).done (item) ->
            $(".price").html item.price
      else #no items selected 
    $(".price").html " "
```

Price displays correctly for a single item selected, but if I have more items selected than I would get `selectedItem.val()` returning 1,2, giving items/1,2.json

#### form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    
    <h3>Items</h3>

    <%= f.association :items, collection: Item.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose an item", input_html: { id: 'item-select2' }, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'span6' } %>

    <div class="product">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="price"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="sub_total">
    <div class="total">
    </div>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My items should be added dynamically, there can be more then 10 items for example. should I be using cocoon gem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not send as data instead of in the url?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/items.json",
  data: { selectedItem: "[" + selectedItem.val() + "]" },
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data) {
  // do something with the data
});
```

Or something along these lines. Rails will still parse json data and give you params[:selectedVal] to use. The use of square brackets is if the val() is comma delimited.

Comment: What if I have many records, 10,000 records, can I specify which records to take and then match with value I need by the id called?

Comment: I think you might want to ask yourself why you are showing 10k records to a user without paging. That smells to me and you may not be happy with the results should you pursue this. The more data you pack in, the closer you will get to a fault where you maxed out the request content size allowed.

Comment: I am using select2 gem: search box with dropdown results instead of selection with paging. So they would search the item and select it and then they can search an additional item. If I pull all the items in the json and choose which ones were selected to display the price. Is there a better way than to pull all the items?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest selecting 10k items in a select either. The main thing is that you do not want to send it in the url. Send it as part of the body.

Comment: why would you not want to send it in the url?

Comment: what does the data do: `data: selectedItem: "[" + selectedItem.val() + "]"`

Comment: if I remove it, I don't see any change, I still get the data showing all the /items.json

Comment: You do not want to send a ton of data in the url. Keep the url clean. data: { selectedItems: "[" + selectedItem.val() + "]" } will send a param to the controller called :selectedItems for you to get this data from. Sending it with the square brackets should make rails see it as an array so you don't have to parse it yourself. In the controller, you will have to do something with that data passed to it. If you are just returning all items then it will only return all items. The return should do whatever operation that action requires on the params[:selectedItems] values input.

Comment: I don't think I have a controller called `:selectedItems`, do I need to make one? If I add or remove that line then nothing changes and I get all the items that exists even if I am calling just one.

Comment: No. In the controller action of the current controller this calls to, ie. /orders/update, you would say something like selected_items = params[:selectedItems]. Then you can iterate through the array or use it in a DB query or however you like.